# I'm creating a twilio application using PHP and having a hard time carrying the RecordingUrl variable

Tags: php, twilio

On the first page of script I ask the caller to give his name and record it, It then goes to the second page where twilio simultaneously dials three numbers.

```
 <?php
    header("content-type: text/xml");
    echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
 ?>
 <Response>
    <Say>please hold while we locate mike</Say>
        <Dial>
            <Number url="hello-monkey-name.php">+12163453546</Number>
            <Number url="hello-monkey-name.php">+12345678968</Number>
        </Dial>
</Response>
```

The url attribute allows me to play things only to the callee and I want to play the recoding from the first page but I dont know how to get the variable to carry, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

If you are using the <Record> verb in the previous page, you can use the [action](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record#attributes-action) attribute to specify a URL to request when the recording is done.  When Twilio requests that URL it will include a few extra parameters beyond the default set:

http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record#attributes-action-parameters

The RecordingUrl parameter will give you the URL to the recording, which you can <Play> to the caller.

Devin

Comment: Thank you for your quick response but I use the action attribute to send the caller to the above page which then runs "hello-monkey-name.php" only to the callee and this is where I want to play the recording.  It is two pages from when it was recorded so do you know of any way to carry the variable to the next page?

Comment: In your case since you have an intermediate page between when you are using the Record verb and when you want to play the audio, you will need to find some way to store the URL that points to the recording.  You could use Session, or store it in a database, or even just URL encode it and append it to the request for hello-monkey-name.php.  Something like this:

hello-monkey-name.php?recordingUrl=[urlencoded_recording_url_here]